# Sort a JavaScript array of strings with years inside

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, date

Evaluating 2 extremely simple arrays, one sorts ok and the other does not:

```
var qtr = ['zzqtr_1_2020','zzqtr_2_2020','zzqtr_3_2019','zzqtr_4_2019'];
qtr.sort();
// qtr is now zzqtr_1_2020, zzqtr_2_2020, zzqtr_3_2019, zzqtr_4_2019 (no change)

var fruits = ["a_1_Banana", "a_2_Orange", "a_1_Apple", "a_1_Mango"];  
fruits.sort();
// fruits is now  a_1_Apple, a_1_Banana, a_1_Mango, a_2_Orange (SORTED!)
```

What I cannot figure out is why the `qtr` array will not be sort properly?

Comment: It *is* sorting, but it's already in sorted order. What do you expect to be different?

Comment: What was your expected result from "_qtr array_" sort?

Comment: I wonder if he's expecting it to be sorted as a date, so that the `2019` items should go before `2020`.

Comment: if you like to get the data sorted by date, you could consider to use strings which have the year in front of the month, like an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date string. this is sortable, despite of the same prefix.

Comment: @NinaScholz Also need 2-digit months, otherwise `12` will sort before `3`

Answer (score 2):

Because the array is already sorted. Your difference is made by the id after "zzqtr_". And the elements are already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is comparing UTF-16 sequences, so `zzqtr_1, zzqtr_2, zzqtr_3, zzqtr_4` is already sorted according to that, the last bit of text (the year) is not relevant there.

I assume you want to sort by year, so in that case, you need to implement a custom sorting function:

```js
const qtr = ['zzqtr_1_2020','zzqtr_2_2020','zzqtr_3_2019','zzqtr_4_2019'];

qtr.sort((a, b) => {
  const aParts = a.split('_');
  const bParts = b.split('_');
  
  return (parseInt(aParts[2]) - parseInt(bParts[2])) || a.localeCompare(b);
});

console.log(qtr.join(', '));
```

Answer (score 0):

The array is already sorted. The string after "zzqtr_" are in increasing order (ie: from 1 to 4). So, if you did something like this:

```
var qtr = ['zzqtr_3_2020','zzqtr_1_2020','zzqtr_4_2019','zzqtr_1_2019'];
qtr.sort();
var x = qtr.toString();
```

now, you will see a change :)

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.sort()` works by comparing UTF-16 code points, which can lead to unexpected results sometimes.

Instead, consider using `String.prototype.localeCompare()` function, which compares two strings, based on the alphabets of the locale and not UTF-16 code points